# C++ Function clarification

Tags: c++, function

Given:

```
  x = MyFunc(2);
```

My understanding:

The variable x is assigned to the function `MyFunc(2)`.

**First, MyFunc( ) is called. When it returns, its return value if any, is assigned to x.**?

Comment: You have changed your last sentence. Now it is "more correct", but in any case, to answer what "its return value if any" means we need the signatire of MyFunc. For example if it is int MyFunc(int), then if it returns (if it does not throw an exception), there will always be a return value. If instead the function is void MyFunc(int), it will never have a return value.

Comment: Sorry I decided to try to clarify a little..., I was actually thinking of editing to add the initial MyFunc(); before I added the argument 2, but I decided against changing it too much, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This cannot be answered completely without:

- x's declaration
- MyFunc's declaration
- MyFunc's definition

But your sentence "When MyFunc(2) is called it returns the value 2 to x" is wrong. MyFunc is invoked and 2 is passed as the actual parameter value. MyFunc may return anything, which is then assigned to x.

Comment: MyFunc may return anything, which is then assigned to x., Okay.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Daniel Daranas
MyFunc is invoked and 2 is passed as the actual parameter value.

Answer (score 7):

No. `x` is assigned to the **evaluated result** of `MyFunc(2)`.

The value returned depends on what `MyFunc` does. It could be anything and does not need to be 2.

Answer (score 3):

No, quite the contrary, you call the function MyFunc over the value 2 and the result is assigned to x

for example

```
int MyFunc( int number ) {
  return number + 1;
}
int x = MyFunc(2);
int y = MyFunc(1);
```

x will be 3 (x+1) and y will be 2

With a different function, the returned value will be different, of course

```
int MyFunc2( int number ) {
  return number - 1;
}
int x = MyFunc2(2);
int y = MyFunc2(1);
```

x will be 1 and y will be 0

The main point is, you've got to declare the function and decide what it returns according to its params.

Comment: Even after you declare the function, the return value if any, will be what get's assigned to the variable as illustrated by you lovely examples, where int x will be 1 and y will be 0 for that last half of your examples, correct?

Comment: Interestingly, I had to resort to the algebraic recall of the number line for those nice examples.

Comment: Thanks guys for the clarification, they should give points here for fastest correct response, i have been on forums where you response might be a week or never-Stack Overflow rocks.